# How to get Telerik MVC Grid data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

How can I pass asp.net mvc telerik grid data to controller using Ajax call.
I need to save the telerik MVC grid data in database.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Please clarify. You cannot submit a grid as it is not an input element.

Answer (score 7):

```
var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
var data = grid.data;
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get any love, but this works wonderfully to get the data from the grid.

Comment: For people searching "How to get data from current selected row in Telerik MVC Grid, JavaScript.":
    onRowSelect(e) { var rowdata = $('#Grid').data('tGrid').data[e.row.rowIndex]; }

Answer (score 2):

I think this [Telerik demo page with code](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax) should help you out.

In the `public partial class GridController : Controller`

there are methods

`public ActionResult EditingAjax`,

`public ActionResult _SelectAjaxEditing()`,

`public ActionResult _InsertAjaxEditing()`

and `public ActionResult _DeleteAjaxEditing`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Model binding on the controller just like you do on a regular form post.  It will also pass the FormCollection object to the controller as well.  I know this is late but hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on h3n's answer, to get at the actual grid data elements / cell values inside of each row of the Telerik grid, you would need code something along these lines:

```
var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
var data = grid.data; 

if(data != null) { // will be null if grid hasn't bound yet
    var rowCount = data.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
    {
        var myData = data[i].ColumnName;
        doSomethingWith(myData);
    }
}
```